# PFFacebookUtils Parse login callback not called with safari

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I'm using the latest version of the ParseFacebookUtils which uses safari to log a user in. The process works as expected where it asks for your permission to your public profile in Safari and returns to the app. The weird behavior is that when the login request returns to the app the code inside of the block is never executed.

It is only executed if I press the login button again or if I set the login behavior to be web-based where a webview is presented within the app. But this isn't the best since the user has to login and they may have forgotten their details. Below is the code which I'm using to log the user in.

```
   PFFacebookUtils.logIn(withPermissions: ["public_profile"]) { user, error in

            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                } else {
                    print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                }
            } else {
                print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
            }
        }
```

Here is the code in my app delegate which I'm using to initialize and handle the url.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseFacebookUtils

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        Parse.initialize(with: ParseConfig.configuration)
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

        // Configure an anon user on startup
        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
        PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground()


        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        return FBAppCall.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: My memory is a bit hazy, but I'm pretty sure that I had this same problem when I was using an outdated version of Facebook sdk. Check that the Facebook sdk is up to date

Comment: @Shayno i have the latest version on the PFUtils SDK which hasn’t been updated in nearly 2 years. I’ve decieded to stick with the webview isn’t the best but it’s more reliable

Comment: Fair enough. I can remember having the same problem recently but can't remember the solutions. Here are the versions that I am using if that helps, `FBSDKCoreKit (4.28.0)`, `FBSDKLoginKit (4.28.0)`, `ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (1.11.1)`.